# Find an example for the function with this property.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

I am thinking to construct two functions $f,g:(0,\infty) \to R$ such that $f(a)<g(b)$, whenever $a,b$ are not equal and $g(a)<f(a)$. Now so far i have been thinking in polynomials only, but the examples like $\frac{4}{3}x^2$ and $\frac{2}{3}x^2$ are holding only one property. Please help me with this one.

Comment: What's the purpose of constructing such functions?

Comment: The main thought in my mind was to construct these functions and study the continuity at these points. That's why i was taking examples of polynomials.

Comment: Any $f, g$ with $g(x) > f(x)$ for all $x$ satisfy your condition (trivially)

Comment: @ArcticChar This is not the case, such functions don't verify $g(a)<f(a)$.

Comment: Can you clarify the placement of the conditions?  Do you mean that for all $a$ and $b$, $g(a) < f(a)$, and if $a \neq b$, then $f(a) < g(b)$?  Or do you mean that for all $a$ and $b$, if $g(a) < f(a)$ and $a \neq b$, then $f(a) < g(b)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar is right because the conditional never occurs when $g(x)>f(x)$ for all $x$. So the statement is true, but trivial.

Comment: As $a\ne b\implies g(a)<f(a)<g(b)$, $g$ is nowhere continuous. At the same time, $g$ forms a local minimum everywhere !?

Comment: It seems there's a lot of confusion in reading your condition. Please clarify.

Comment: The first question in Mr. Matthew's comment is exactly what i am asking.

Comment: can we construct these type of functions piece wise?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood your problem. But in my opinion you cannot construct such functions. Assume $f,g$ exist then you have for any integer $n \geq2$:

$ g(1)>f(n)>g(n)$ and $g(n)>f(1)>g(1)$ which cannot be true.

Comment: To generalize, for any $a \neq 1$, $g(a) > f(1) > g(1) > f(a) > g(a)$